# Will I receive a payment data transfer from PayPal each time a payment is processed for a subscription?

Tags: paypal, payments, subscription

I have searched PayPal, Google, and Bing for details regarding Payment Data Transfer (PDT) and subscriptions, without result.

My question is, For each recurrence of a subscription payment will I receive a PDT request?

I understand that the first PDT is requested/initiated by the payer's browser.  For subsequent payments though, will PayPal initiate a PDT request, or will I have to create an Instant Payment Notification (IPN) endpoint?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create an instant payment notification endpoint. The payment data transfer request is achieved through the use of forwarding the user browser with key data back to your application. as a subscription payment does not involve the user being logged in with a browser session active this can not be done so the only way is through an IPN endpoint being configured to receive the data to.